# Rendering animation as stills or MP4?

Tags: animation, video, network

I have an architectural animation of about 400 frames ( a part of a larger compilation). At about two minutes per frame, it will take more than thirteen  hours so, I was going to connect a second computer, pull up the same file across the network, and check the "place holder" feature and have both computers rendering the same file. Now, rendering to an MP4 is fairly new in Blender and, though I prefer rendering straight to video, I'm a bit wary about any issues I might run across with this new feature. I'll be pulling the finished render into Premiere Pro for further editing with HD videos, commentary, and stills. So, video or stills? Stills would mean stitching together, not a terribly hard thing to do in Premiere but that MP4 would be way easier. Just hate to get thirteen hours into a render and find the network/placeholder method has issues with video.

Comment: Stills are always a good idea. If you crash or need to quit the program for any reason you can pick up where you left off.

Answer (score 4):

I do not recommend you to render directly to video.

If any error occurs during this render, you will lost all the movie.

Rendering in frames (stills) you can render in parts, also in case of error, you can render the remaining frames later.

Use the video editor to render the stills to the final video.

Comment: Ideally too, render to EXR half or full. If bandwidth is an issue, use DWAA compression.

Comment: And using the VSE to stitch them together takes almost no time.